# dplyr subquery inside join function

Tags: r, dplyr

The ususal syntax of dplyr join functions are

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Key"))
```

considering the fact same key exists in both datasets.
Is there a way to write pipe operators inside join functions instead of creating another dataset?
E.g

```
df1 %>% mutate(something = some_calc) %>% filter(some filter) left_join(df2 %>% mutate(some filter), by c("key"))
```

I am getting out of bounds error while joining.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(something = some_calc) %>% 
  filter(some filter) %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(some filter), by = c("key"))
```

Should work.